# Memory allocation in C malloc()

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

i'm a little bit confused about the behavioral of this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* foo(){
   char* arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
   return arr;
}

void foo1(char* myArr){
 char* arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
 myArr = arr;
}

int main(){
  char* myArr;
  foo1(myArr);
  myArr[23] = 'a';
  printf("%c", myArr[23]);
  return (0);
```

}

When i call `myArr = foo()`, it works just fine and the value of an allocated memory address will assigned to `myArr` and i have an allocated memory segment with no errors. On the other hand, when i call the function `foo1(myArr)` it has to pass `myArr` to the function, it's a pointer to a segment so any changes with this pointers will affect the memory segment, (for example if i want to swap two string values, i can simply swap the pointers), but i will get a `segmentation fault error`, why? because myArr is not myArr in `main` function? is that true?!!

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).... Study for inspiration the source code of *existing* open source projects on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). You'll learn a lot by contributing to some of them. Wirth GCC, compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: If you use a *real* compiler, it has a static code checker. `clang -analyze..` But you could as well simply notice that your argument lacks one level of indirection for your stuff to work.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, After reading some parts of this book that, you mentioned (Modern C), i've found it really intresting and it helped a lot to my knowledge about C programming language. I want to really thank you about introducing this book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call two different variables `myArr`, which is probably confusing you. Changes to the `myArr` in `foo1` have no affect on the `myArr` in `main` just because they have the same name. You pass the value of the `myArr` in `main` to `foo1`, but nothing is returned.

```
void foo1(char* myArr){
 char* arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
 myArr = arr;
}
```

This is no different conceptually from:

```
void foo1(int j) {
    int q = 2;
    j = q;
}
```

Just as `foo1(3)` wouldn't somehow turn that `3` into a `2`, `foo1(myArr)` doesn't change the value of `myArr`. That `myArr` is a pointer doesn't change its semantics -- C is pass by value, period. So only `myArr`'s value is passed to the function.

```
  char* myArr;
  foo1(myArr);
```

Notice that `myArr` is not assigned a value here, so you are passing `foo1` the value of a pointer to nothing in particular. There is nothing useful `foo1` can do with that value.

You probably want:

```
void foo1(char** myArrPtr){
 char* arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
 *myArrPtr = arr;
}
```

and

```
 char* myArr;
 foo1(&myArr);
```

That way, the function gets a pointer to `myArr` and then modifies the thing that pointer points to, which is the `myArr` in `main`.

Comment: so if i want to fix that i have to change `void foo1(char* myArr)`  to `void foo1(char** myArr)` and in the main function, i have to call `foo1` like this `foo1(&myArr)` and that would solve the issue. thanks.

Comment: @AliNaderiParizi That's correct. That way, you pass a pointer to `myArr` rather than its (unspecified and meaningless) value.

Comment: And, the memory allocated in the function is remaining there and never will be freed. is this `memory lack`?

Comment: @AliNaderiParizi In this case, the caller of `foo1` would usually be responsible for `free`ing the memory when it's finished with it. But this code is just meant to show how to properly use a pointer, it's not realistic code.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments in C are *always* call-by-value -- the argument gets a *copy* of what the caller passes and is a new variable, so if the function changes the value of the argument it does not affect the value of whatever was passed in.  So when you call

```
foo1(myArr);
```

the value of `myArr` will not change, even if foo1 assigns a different value to it.